# Why are piecewise linear functions semismooth?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

I came across the following exercise, namely proofing that for the minimumfunction f(a,b) = min(a,b) for $ x = (a,b)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$, it holds for every point that

sup $|f(x+s)-f(x) - Ms| = O(||s||^2)$ for $||s|| \to 0$ where $M$ is an element of Clarke's generalized differential at x+s.

It is clear that at points where $x_1 \neq x_2$, this holds (as then f is linear, the only element in Clarke's differential is its Jacobian and everything cancels. However, I seem to miss the idea for $x_1 = x_2$.

This generalizes to arbitrary piecewise linear functions, hence the title.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How did $f$ change from a function in two arguments to a function in just one argument?  What is this "Clarke differential"?

Comment: @user43208 sorry for the bad notation! From the second paragraph on, x is an element of R^2. Clarke's differential is the convex hull of the b-differential, which itself is all possible limits of gradients of sequences in the differential locus converging to the given point (in this case x+s).

Comment: They are semialgebraic functions, and semialgebraic functions are semismooth with respect to the clarke subdifferential.

Comment: @JürgenSukumaran is there a good source for an (elementary) proof of this? Especially because I am searching for a proof of strongly semismooth (i.e. 2-order semismooth) and not only semismoothness.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good source online to answer this question: It holds in general for $PC^2$ (piecewise $C^2$-functions) that they are first order semismooth. A proof is given in "Semismooth Newton Methods for Variational Inequalities and Constrained Optimization Problems in Function Spaces", (M. Ulbrich) Proposition 2.2.6.

The basic idea (that was missing for me) was to write $M$ as a convex combination of the elements in the B-differential and then to use Taylor to get an upper bound.

Comment: I would be interested to see your proof in detail if you'd share it :)